# Unable to set background color and clear the output in EGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl, grafika

I have tried below sample code in Android to  learn OpenGL. but i could not see the output expected.  Please point out where is the issue ?

I have used fadden's contribution as a reference.

[grafika-fadden](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java)

Step 1:

I have created renderThread with renderHandler.

```
 public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new RenderHandler(this);

        mEconEglCore = new EGLCore(null, EGLCore.FLAG_RECORDABLE);
        EGLSurface eglSur =  mEconEglCore.createWindowSurface(userSurface);


        synchronized (mStartLock) {
            mReady = true;
            mStartLock.notifyAll();
        }
        Looper.loop();
    }
```

The userSurface  I have received in the RenderThread Constructor.

```
 public RenderThread(Surface surface) {
       // Log.d (TAG, "Inside Render Thread..");
        userSurface = surface;

    }
```

Now, i am  Invoking doFrame() API with the help of Choreographer Callback mechanism to just draw colors in the surface.

```
 GLES20.glLineWidth(3.0f);
 GLES20.glClearColor(0.6f, 1.0f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
 GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

NOTE: Application uses TextureView and have received the surface in the following manner.

```
 mytextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Surface Texture Available..");
                userSurface = new Surface(surface);
```

PROBLEM:

I am not sure if i am aligned with right procedure in OpenGL Coding. Also, I dont see any color displayed in the surface, but only black color. Even if i do not do anything i do black color.

Kindly provide input. Also, let know the missing part that i need to be aware of ?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the mistake that i have committed.

1) I have created or associated the surface to EGL Context by using

```
   eglCreateWindowSurface
```

**Missed the below two steps:**

2). But,  I forgot to inform the current surface to EGL Context. So, i made this.

```
 EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, eglUserSurface, eglUserSurface,
            mEGLContext);
```

3) we need to swapBuffer.of the surface. That i have done by

```
 EGL14.eglSwapBuffers(mEGLDisplay, eglUserSurface);
```

Now, i see my surface color has got changed to green Color.

Learned something new today. Thanks.